# Nginx Proxy http://example.com root to different folders on other systemeg http://ip:9000/folder

Tags: nginx, proxy

I would like to use nginx to proxy / to another IP:9000/folder

I want to setup a nginx proxy that will listen on example.com and then nginx must pass it to privateip-serverb:9000/myapp

My location block looks as follows:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://privateip-serverb:9000/myapp;
    proxy_redirect default;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

This unfortunately does not work because we have things like http://privateip-serverb:9000/myapp/login etc that now does not work.

Not sure how to go about this

Comment: Is `myapp` an app that is being served by something else (eg by a wsgi)? If so, can't you proxy directly to the port on which it's listening?

Comment: Hi. It seems i will have to that yes. The java app is currently build to listen on port 9000/appname. But we will remove /appname and let it listen on the root.